# first time in perl OpenGL

Tags: perl

awesome programmers.... im trying to studying perl opengl... i install all the modules and it went ok.. everythings fine! except for this...
my first code is

```
use OpenGL;
use SDL;

glpOpenWindow();

print "Return to exit\n";

while(<>){
exit;
}
```

and the result is
Goto undefined subroutine &AutoLoader::AUTOLOAD at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/OpenGL.pm line 6110.

i tried the test.pl of OpenGL.. awesomely works fine but this line of me is weird!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the source code of method `AUTOLOAD` from [OpenGL.pm](https://metacpan.org/source/CHM/OpenGL-0.6703/OpenGL.pm)

```
sub AUTOLOAD {
    # This AUTOLOAD is used to 'autoload' constants from the constant()
    # XS function.  If a constant is not found then control is passed
    # to the AUTOLOAD in AutoLoader.

    # NOTE: THIS AUTOLOAD FUNCTION IS FLAWED (but is the best we can do for now).
    # Avoid old-style ``&CONST'' usage. Either remove the ``&'' or add ``()''.
    if (@_ > 0) {

        # Is it an old OpenGL-0.4 function? If so, remap it to newer variant
    local($constname);
    ($constname = $AUTOLOAD) =~ s/.*:://;
    if (grep ($_ eq $constname, @rename_old)) {
        eval "sub $AUTOLOAD { $AUTOLOAD" . "_s(\@_) }";
        goto &$AUTOLOAD;
    }

        $AutoLoader::AUTOLOAD = $AUTOLOAD;
        goto &AutoLoader::AUTOLOAD; #LINE 6110
    }
```

They have put in comment that `THIS AUTOLOAD FUNCTION IS FLAWED` so maybe the warning you are getting is not due to your program but the problem with module itself.

Comment: so u know how to debug this??.. or something!!,

Comment: solved it... i just opened the test.pl of openGL the line they use is glpcOpenWindow instead of glpOpenWindow.. thats totally.. awesome ...

Comment: You can write your answer and accept it so that it doesn't appear in "unanswered questions" list.